# how to do the sum of 2 columns adding that into new column by reading the csv file in shell script

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, awk, cmd

I'm trying to implement shell script to read csv file and do the sum of 2 columns  and adding into new column called total. But it's not successfully done. please suggest how can I achieve this.

my input csv file

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

expected output

```
a,b,c,total
1,2,3,5
4,5,6,11
```

**Here a is a primary key**

I tried below code to achieve this

```
echo "First arg: 1"
awk "{print $3 $2 """""" $1}"
echo "First arg: 2
awk -F, "{$(NF+1)=Null;}1" OFS=, file.csv
awk -F "," "{print $1,$2,$3,$2+$3}"
```

my output is:

```
C:\Users\inrenan\NIFI\NIFI-1~1.2-B\NIFI-1~1.2>awk -F "," "{print $1,$2,$3,$2+$3}" 
a b c 0
1 2 3 5
4 5 6 11
```

only I'm facing the issue is column name

Comment: "But it's not successfully done." What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: @SamBob Please check the question again I updated

Comment: Moderator: this question is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980230/use-awk-to-sum-all-cells-in-a-csv as currently marked. This question sums each row individually, that questions sums all columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the awk script you need:

```
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } { print $0, (NR==1 ? "total" : $2+$3) }
```

Do whatever magical incantation you have to to use it in Windows.

In Unix you'd just do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } { print $0, (NR==1 ? "total" : $2+$3) }' input
a,b,c,total
1,2,3,5
4,5,6,11
```

but I hear Windows has some odd quoting rules that are best avoided and so the common advice I see given for Windows is to save the script in a file named, say, script.awk (which you could also do in Unix) and invoke it as:

```
awk -f script.awk input
a,b,c,total
1,2,3,5
4,5,6,11
```

Based on the last script in your question, this **might** work for you in Windows but I really don't know Windows quoting rules:

```
awk "BEGIN{ FS=OFS=\",\" } { print $0, (NR==1 ? \"total\" : $2+$3) }" input
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Here mentioning an `awk` variable named `fields` which has value of `2,3` we could mention field numbers there separated by `,` and it will take care of taking sum of all those fields.

```
awk -v fields="2,3" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  num=split(fields,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    field[arr[i]]
  }
}
FNR==1 { print $0,"total"; next }
FNR>1{
  sum=0
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(i in field){ sum+=$i }
  }
  $(NF+1)=sum
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

For a very cumbersome one-liner:

```
awk -F',' '{if (NR==1) {printf "%s,total\n",$0;} else {sum=0; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {sum +=$i}; {printf "%s,%s\n",$0,sum;}}}' file.csv
```

Comment: i'm using `.bat` file to write shell script and I faced the above error, I changed the `'` to `"` but facing same issue

Comment: I guess you are running in windows. Are you sure then that you are running `bash` and not `cmd.exe`? What are you running your script with (which program and what command)?

Comment: yes I'm running in the windows by using the `.bat` format file and I updated the output of my code please check it

Comment: "In the windows" from cmd? Powershell? WSL? If either of the first two this is not a bash question as tagged. This solution is for bash.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure Batch-file that get the desired output:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P "header=" < input.txt
echo !header!,total
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set /A "total=%%b+%%c"
   echo %%a,%%b,%%c,!total!
)
```